# How to get dynamic word from particular pattern using Regex in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to parse my .cs class which is having module aggregator. I want to get the Name of all the concrete class which i'm passing in those module handlers.
so I want to get the Name "ConfigurationContextBuilder" from the following line.

```
ModuleHandlerAggregator.TryCreateOrGet<ConfigurationContextBuilder>()
```

I tried following regex code but i'm not getting desired word.

`/ModuleHandlerAggregator.TryCreateOrGet<.*?>()/g`

Comment: I don't see `ConfigurationContextBuilder` anywhere in what you provided.

Comment: it was getting disappeared when i use < > (arrow) operator. so I've replaced < > with ~ sign

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.`, `(`, and `)` are used in regex patterns, so you need to escape them using a backslash to make them match literally.

So the following regular expression will fix your problem:

[`ModuleHandlerAggregator\.TryCreateOrGet<(.*?)>\(\)`](https://regex101.com/r/FOkf1n/2)

Comment: Although this should be considered, OP's own solution also should match it (unless `m` modifier is set)

Answer (score 0):

you can use the regex as:

```
<(\S*)>
```

https://regex101.com/r/IkKymu/2

Thanks